# Context values not updating in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a counter app in React js using context api for global state management .

But the problem is when i am clicking increase and decrease button it is not updating global values .

I am new to react , please provide guidance what is going wrong here .

ContextFile :

```
import {createContext,useState} from 'react';

export const DataContext = createContext({
    data:0,
    increase : () => {},
    decrease : () => {}
});

function DataContextProvider(props){
    const [data,setData] = useState();

    const increase = () => {
        setData(data + 1);
    }

    const decrease = () => {
        setData(data - 1);
    }

    return(
        <DataContext.Provider value={{data,increase,decrease}}>
            {props.children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    );

};

export default DataContextProvider;
```

App.js :

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import {DataContext} from './Context/dataContext';
import DataContextProvider from './Context/dataContext';
import IncreaseBtn from './Component/Increase';
import DecreaseBtn from './Component/Decrease';

const App = () => {
  const {data} = useContext(DataContext);
  
  return(
    <>
    <DataContextProvider>
      {data}
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <IncreaseBtn />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <DecreaseBtn />
    </DataContextProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Increase Button Component :

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import {DataContext} from '../Context/dataContext';

const IncreaseBtn = () => {
    const {increase} = useContext(DataContext);

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={increase}> Increase </button>
        </>
    )
}

export default IncreaseBtn;
```

Decrease Button Component :

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import {DataContext} from '../Context/dataContext';

const DecreaseBtn = () => {
    const {decrease} = useContext(DataContext);

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={decrease}> Decrease </button>
        </>
    )
}

export default DecreaseBtn;
```

Folder Structure :
[image]

Comment: I would give an initial state of say `useState(0)` or any number ... just a point * as by default it takes `undefined` as initial state value ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to use `context` you should wrap your `provider` around those components, but here `App` component isn't wrapped but to its children
- Give an initial state of some "number" as it would be `undefined` and it gives `NaN` if you do the arithmetic operations with it.

[Updated the sandbox for your ref](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-sun-cmngx3?file=/src/Component/Decrease.js)

Comment: Exactly , i have done this and values are updating now .

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the state in the wrong way
Try:
`setCount(count => count + 1);`

Comment: That's not the issue though